# this is impossible? chat php with sql messages horizontally

Tags: php

I have this chat, consists of two files  index.php and chat.lib.php

chat.lib.php

> ```
>     function connect_easy($query) {
>         $b = array();
>
>         if(!$connect = mysql_connect($this->host,$this->user,$this->pass));
>
>         if(!$dbr = mysql_select_db($this->db));
>
>         if(!($result = mysql_query($query)));
>         @$num = mysql_num_rows($result);
>         @$num2 = mysql_num_fields($result);
>         for($x=0;$x<$num;$x++) {
>             $a = mysql_fetch_array($result);
>             for($i=0;$i<$num2;$i++) {
>                 $b[$x][$i] = html_entity_decode($a[$i]);
>             }
>
>         }
>
>         return $b;
>     }
>
>
>     function show($a) {
>
>         if(count($a)>0) {
>             $a=array_reverse($a);
>             if(count($a)<3) $end=count($a);
>             else $end=3;
>             for($i=0;$i<$end;$i++) {
>                 echo "<font size=2 color=red>".$a[$i][1]."</font>: ".$a[$i][0]."<br />";
>             }
>
>         }
>
>     }
>
> }
> ```

this show 3 messages vertical like

hour:message1

hour:message2

hour:message3

**but how edit this code for show horizontally messages like**

hour:message1   hour:message2   hour:message3

**thanks if you can help me**

**excuse my english**

Comment: Nothing is impossible, you just need the skill!

Comment: Remove the break tag...

Comment: `."<br />"` => `." "` - *Easy as Mmm... pie*. No, not that kind of... 3.14

Comment: If you want them horizontal, why are you outputting a `<br>` after every message?

Comment: Font tag... ***choking***

Comment: thanks all really internet is nothing without people like you helping

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply remove the line break and add whatever separator you'd like:

```
for($i=0;$i<$end;$i++) {
    echo "<span class='red'>".$a[$i][1]."</span>: ".$a[$i][0]." ";
    //                                                   here ^^^
}
```

I've also removed the 20th century font tag and replaced it with a span with a class "red". Adjust the CSS accordingly:

```
span.red {
    color: red;
}
```

Comment: yes men it work i am a newbie thank you all

Comment: It has to work. :) You're welcome!

Answer (score 0):

Remove the "br" tag from your echo.